# php session lock

Tags: php, session

I want the code snippet

```
 echo "This is a test";
```

to be printed once every hour. So when the user loades index.php the first time it should be printed. When the user immediately after that reloads the page it should dissapear. After one hour it should be printed again...
How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["last_shown"]))             // If the session variable 
                                                 // was never set
or ($_SESSION["last_shown"] < (time() - 3600))   // or was set more than
                                                 // 1 hour (3600 secs) ago
 {
  echo "This is a test";                         // Make output
  $_SESSION["last_shown"] = time();              // Update session variable 
                                                 // with current time
 }
```

Comment: This won't work if you forgot to run the script after exactly one hour, for example after 1 hour and a half.

Comment: @Sandy mmmm, @Artefact makes a good point! The next counter will start counting down one hour *after the user makes the request*, which may not be what you want. Making it truly hourly is tougher. Depends on what you want.

Comment: @Sandy @Michael's answer has the same problem though

Answer (score 3):

Rather than sessions, set a cookie to expire in 1 hour. on page load, if the cookie is there don't display the message.  The advantage over sessions is that the user can close the browser and return later (if you want that)

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['sesslock']))
{
  // No cookie - show message & set cookie (expires in 1 hour, 3600sec)
  setcookie('sesslock','ok', time()+3600);
  echo "this is a test";
}
else
{
  // The cookie is there, don't display your message
}
```

Comment: A nice alternative. Also immune to race conditions

Comment: Should work, unless the user's paranoid and has all cookies deleted at browser close. But then, the session method would fail for this user too.

Comment: In terms of running exactly hourly, however, this has the same problem as my approach - it won't count for exactly the same minute of the hour, but from when the user makes the request

Comment: One hour after first visit was how I understood the question. Doing it hourly on the hour is indeed a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the current time to a $_SESSION variable and if the user changes the page check the session time variable. 
and if that time is greater than one hour, than display the message